# If Statement not working with double

Tags: java

I am a beginner programmer learning Java.  I am doing an exercise where the user enters the number of minutes, and I print out the number of years and days.

I have put together some if statements to print out the amount of years & days, or days only depending on the amount of minutes the user entered.

The if statements fail to work (the first statement gets executed) if the variable year is a double.  As soon as I narrow it to an (int) it works fine.  I tested it with 2880 minutes, so the value for year should be clearly less than one, and the second if else statement should be executed.

Any help on why this is happening would be appreciated (I am aware that doubles are not totally accurate, but my test case should work as the value for years should be way below 1).  Thanks!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NumberOfYears {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Set up Scanner object
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Get the number of minutes from the user
        System.out.print("Enter the number of minutes: ");
        int minutes = input.nextInt();

        //Determine the amount days / years
        double days = minutes / 60.0 / 24;
        double years = days / 365.0;

        //Print out results
        if ( years > 0) {
            System.out.println(minutes + " minutes is approximately " + (int) years + " years and " + (int) days % 365
                    + " days.");
        } else if ( days > 0) {
            System.out.println(minutes + " minutes is approximately " + (int) days + " days.");
        } else {
            System.out.println(minutes + " minutes is less than one day.");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `years > 0` should be `((int) years) > 0` - `0.x` is greater than zero, but less than one.

Comment: ie you want (double) years ? instead of (int) years ?

Comment: If you enter 2880 minutes, years should be less than one but greater than 0, so the first if statement got executed. And you cast years to int, it will make it to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your if statement, you wrote `if (years > 0)`. Should be `if (years > 1)`. Same with your `if (days > 0)`. Simple as that. There is nothing wrong with floating point math in java or your usage.

Comment: For whatever positive `minute` input you feed it, `year > 0` is always going to be true.

Answer (score 0):

I get the following:

```
Enter the number of minutes: 2880
2880 minutes is approximately 0.005479452054794521 years and 2 days.
```

code seems to work fine when casting years as a double

Answer (score 0):

I would say the correct approach is to have `int` types for days and years as well. Then, use integer division (described [here](https://mathbits.com/MathBits/Java/DataBasics/Mathoperators.htm)) to calculate the number of days and years. There is no reason to have day and year `double` variables.